# Remove rows from dataframe based on condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have one dataframe with two columns:

```
+--------+-----+
|    col1| col2|
+--------+-----+
|22      | 12.2|
|1       |  2.1|
|5       | 52.1|
|2       | 62.9|
|77      | 33.3|
```

I would like to create a new dataframe which will take only rows where

> "value of col1" > "value of col2"

Just as a note the **col1 has long** type and **col2 has double** type

the result should be like this:

```
+--------+----+
|    col1|col2|
+--------+----+
|22      |12.2|
|77      |33.3|
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possible way could be using a `where` function of DF.

For example this:

```
val output = df.where("col1>col2")
```

will give you the expected result:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|  22|12.2|
|  77|33.3|
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 22):

I think the best way would be to simply use "filter".

```
df_filtered=df.filter(df.col1>df.col2)
df_filtered.show()

+--------+----+
|    col1|col2|
+--------+----+
|22      |12.2|
|77      |33.3|
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way to keep rows based on a condition is to use `filter`, as mentioned by others.

To answer the question as stated in the title, one option to remove rows based on a condition is to use left_anti join in Pyspark.
For example to delete all rows with col1>col2 use:

```
rows_to_delete = df.filter(df.col1>df.col2)

df_with_rows_deleted = df.join(rows_to_delete, on=[key_column], how='left_anti')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sqlContext to simplify the challenge.

first register as temp table as example:
`df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl1")`
then run the sql like
`sqlContext.sql("select * from tbl1 where col1 > col2")`

Comment: you can use below to create sqlContext: `from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc).sparkSession`

Comment: thank you! as I right understood sqlContext.sql(...) will return a dataframe right ?