# Dropping rows from a spark dataframe based on a condition

Tags: pyspark

I want to drop rows from a spark dataframe of lists based on a condition. The condition is the length of the list being a certain length.

I have tried converting it into a list of lists and then using a for loop (demonstrated below) but I'm hoping to do it in one statement within spark and just creating a new immutable df from the original df based on this condition.

```
newList = df2.values.tolist()

finalList = []

for subList in newList:
    if len(subList) < 4:
        finalList.append(subList)
```

So for instance, if the dataframe is a one column dataframe and the column is named sequences, it looks like:

```
sequences
____________
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 6, 3]
[9, 1, 4, 6]
```

I want to drop all rows where the length of the list is more than 3, resulting in:

```
sequences
____________
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 6, 3]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove rows from dataframe based on condition in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395986/remove-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-condition-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is one approach in Spark >= 1.5 using the build-in `size` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import  size

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=[9, 3, 4], b=[8,9,10]),Row(a=[7, 2, 6, 4], b=[2,1,5]), Row(a=[7, 2, 4], b=[8,2,1,5]), Row(a=[2, 4], b=[8,2,10,12,20])])

df.where(size(df['a']) <= 3).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------------+
|        a|                 b|
+---------+------------------+
|[9, 3, 4]|        [8, 9, 10]|
|[7, 2, 4]|      [8, 2, 1, 5]|
|   [2, 4]|[8, 2, 10, 12, 20]|
+---------+------------------+
```